# Why wouldn’t they try to re-invent automobiles?

Tags: internal-consistency

5 Centuries after the apocalypse, the city of San Francisco has made humongous leap back towards civilization. Their city has the most advanced medical, nuclear, and engineering technology, and are even starting their own space travel agency, and have sent 3 satellites into orbit. Even though they have all of this technology, they still haven’t tried to reinvent automobiles to use for transportation.

So my question is, is it plausible for the SF-ers to not have automobiles, but still have an advanced civilization?

Comment: SF is a poor place to launch rockets.  Invade south, and launch from SoCal.

Comment: That’s were they launch from. They have an embassy in SoCal, and they lets them launch there

Comment: By "automobile" I suspect you really mean petrol or diesel driven engine.  There are ways to drive a wheeled vehicle without these and you still have an automobile.  Please clarify.

Comment: I mean a regular automobile, I.e. a car powered by oil or electricity

Comment: We burned all the easily (and even pretty difficultly) accessible oil.  Where are they getting it from?

Comment: Generally, this question is asked in such a way as to ask the answer-er to make up their own reason. It seems like you are asking the people here to write a plot point for your story. That is something we try to discourage, which is why your question is now on hold. A better approach is to make a proposal and ask if it is reasonable. This is a 'reality check' question, such as  'Is it plausible that SF-ers didn't invent automobiles at all because they have a cable car system' or something.

Comment: @RonJohn [Biofuels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biofuel) are an option for engine fuel.

Comment: @StephenG you'd need a **lot** of crops for that.  (It's why only places like tropical Brazil -- with their year 'round ability to harvest a large plant that has a **high** content of simple sugars -- heavily use biofuels.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There isn't a plausible reason**

Yours is an example of what I call a "technology dichotomy."  Technology exists that depends on an earlier technology, but that earlier technology doesn't exist.  This can't be so.

The technologies you describe depend on ground transportation.  You could claim that the city jumped over wheeled, combustion automobiles and went straight to hoover craft or gravitics, but that's just sophistry.

The truth is you must move materials.  Raw materials.  Manufactured materials.  Food, metal, wood, you name it.  The amount of goods that demand transport for a high-tech society of any reasonable size (and you'd need tens if not hundreds of thousands *minimum* to support nuclear power and a space program) is astronomical.  And before you had a space program and nuclear power, you had carts, which would lead very naturally to motorized carts (aka, automobiles).

And it's the nature of all things (from evolution to working in an office) to take the path of least resistance.  If it's cheaper to build a wheel, you'll use it to pull potatoes, even if you have gravitics.

I'd say you were trying to put the cart before the horse, but in reality, you're trying to put space flight before the cart — and that's impossible.

Comment: I never said they had hover crafts or gravitics

Comment: The @JaycieBeveri answer is the *perfect* plausible reason.

Comment: @RonJohn perfect?  They have space flight and nuclear power, but no automatic transmission?  Have you ever looked iinto what it takes to feed a city?

Comment: @Qualos, No, you didn't.  I'm merely using them as examples.  How do you intend to feed your city and provide the raw materials for your advanced technology without automobiles?

Comment: @JBH, they have slave workers on the outside who do the farming and mining work.

Comment: @Qualos ok, they're a slave society.  How does the (agricultural and mineral) fruit of the earth get from the source to the city?  (I've got more questions if you say "rail".)

Comment: There is a fairly plausible reason: no more fossil fuels, and battery tech that's still at ~1980 levels.  You can run a sizeable city on rail and horse-drawn transport - say London or Paris at the turn of the 20th century.  If you have electricity from hydro power, but no fossil fuels, you can run electric rail just about anywhere.

Comment: @RomJohn, they have an electric railroad that goes all the way from there city all the way to San Bernardino. The railroad was built 200 years before my Story starts.

Comment: @Qualos: But there's another thing to watch out for.  Without the California & Colorado River aquaduct systems, most of southern California goes back to semi-desert, so no large population there.

Comment: @jamesqf:The SFers helped repair the aquaduct the working order, so some cities with populations around 10,000 are possible, though nowhere near today’s level

Comment: @Qualos, you can't have nuclear power and a space program with just 10,000 people.  High tech requires a pyramid of service providers that's enormous.  Further, if you have nuclear power, you have pumps and desalination.  You can't delaninate for millions, but you can for tens and hundreds of thousands.

Comment: @JBH: No I meant some towns in SoCal have populations of 10,000. San Francisco has a population of 2 million, the cities with 10,000 don’t have the technology the SF has

Comment: @Qualos: Why would they have done the repair, though?  I'm assuming your future world has a much lower population than currently, so what's the point of repeating the mistake of building/repairing expensive infrastructure to support a large population in the LA Basin, when there are so many places in California that are pleasantly habitable with minimal tech?

Answer (score 4):

It is San Francisco.  They have expanded their cable car system everywhere.

And the wire-pullers' guild is powerful enough to prohibit using an engine to power a wheeled vehicle.

Comment: I like this one. It's similar to the collusion to keep electric cars off the market, and you can expand it to however many guilds/unions are involved in the operation and maintenance of the system.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever been to San Francisco? It's hilly. I mean, it's renowned-for-being-hilly-hilly. All those steep hills are heck on manual transmissions, and at the beginning of the car era, manual was all anyone had - automatic wasn't invented until 1921.

At this point in time in your story, automatic transmission hasn't been invented. So either they treat cars as a curiosity that's been invented elsewhere, or as an idea that would be impractical in reality.

Comment: An automated transmission is not required to create an automobile.  In fact you don't even need selectable gears - that just makes things more efficient for some engines.  I have no idea why you think manual transmission is a problem for "hilly" driving - it's done all over the world.

Comment: @StephenG - Wouldn't a single gear car still need to... downshift, somehow, to come to a stop?

Comment: @AlexP - So, you live in a city of almost entirely 20+ percent grade hills, and multiple stoplights up each hill, *and* the average manual transmission in your city doesn't need repairs sooner in its lifetime than an average manual transmission in a city that's flat? http://www.sftravel.com/article/san-francisco’s-hills-their-dizziest San Francisco is punishing on manual transmissions, and that has nothing to do with what I may or may not believe about them. There's no reason to use someone pointing out geographic facts as an opportunity to be snide by taking her statement out of context.

Comment: @JaycieBeveri: How did the residents of S.F. cope before the invention of automatic gear boxes? You are right that automatics are of course better suited than manual transmissions for urban driving *in general*; and urban driving plus hilly terrain do indeed induce a tendency for clutches to wear more quickly. But that's not the point; the point is, would a lack of automatic gearboxes preclude the use of automobiles in a hilly city: and the answer is quite obviously no, it wouldn't. They had motor cars in S.F. before automatic gearboxes, and even before the invention of synchronized gearboxes.

Comment: @JaycieBeveri To stop an a wheeled vehicle you need to apply friction, typically to the driving wheels but it can also be done by directly increasing contact with the ground.  The gear you are in has nothing to do with stopping.  Gears have to do with slowing down by allowing engine revs to remain optimal while using gearing ratio to reduce the rotational speed of the drive wheel (and of course the opposite).  However in first gear (the lowest manual gear) your car will *still* try to move forward, as it will will in reverse (and most cars have only one reverse gear).  Brakes stop you.

Comment: @StephenG - I might formulate this into its own question, but: how likely would it be for brakes to go out in an early car, on a hill with a 20% grade? Would it be 1 in 100 cars per year? One in 1000? Would the chances increase over the lifetime of the brakes?

Comment: @AlexP - "...would a lack of automatic gearboxes preclude the use of automobiles in a hilly city: and the answer is quite obviously no, it wouldn't," does not make the same assumptions as "...their strange belief that manual transmissions are difficult to operate." You took the question and my response out of context, and you made a jerk out yourself doing it.

Comment: But if the future San Francisco is going to have more than a very small population, it is going to have to at least expand farmlands outside the hilly part of the current city.  So perhaps no one uses transport in the hills (but why do they live there, rather than more congenial places?), but they need farmers &c living outside, and some form of transport to bring food and other materials in.

Comment: @jamesqf - Not necessarily. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_agriculture Having toured SF's waste management and recycling facilities, I have to wonder how they'll continue composting their food if they're restricted to the peninsula. But I felt all of that would be outside the bounds of the question, as written.

Comment: @Jaycie Beveri: While "urban agriculture" might produce useful quantitities of fresh vegetables & fruits to supply upscale restaurants, it simply doesn't work to support the needs of a large population.  It's just a matter of insolation per unit area times the (quite low) efficiency of photosynthesis.